# "TypeError: cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" when Jest testing react component that includes c3 chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, c3.js

I have a react component that imports c3 and builds a c3 chart. Works fine, I can see the c3 chart.

I'm trying to test my react code with Jest, so I started a simple test for my react component, just an import for the component and test that verifies the component is 'truthy' (not null/not undefined), but I'm getting the following error when trying to run the test:

```
● Test suite failed to run

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined


  at node_modules/c3/c3.js:3578:29
  at node_modules/c3/c3.js:4266:5
  at node_modules/c3/c3.js:3:83
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/c3/c3.js:6:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/ChartPanel.tsx:2075:49)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/module.ts:131:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/module.test.ts:1:1)
```

Any idea? What am I missing here?

Example:
Here is code using a react sample app, just modified it to include a custom component with simple c3 chart:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Chart } from './Chart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-link-container">
        <a className="App-link"
           href="https://reactjs.org"
           target="_blank"
           rel="noopener noreferrer">
           Learn React
        </a>
      </div>
      <Chart />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Chart.js (component with very simple c3 chart)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import c3 from 'c3';

export class Chart extends PureComponent {
  _chart;

  componentDidMount() {
    this._renderChart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._renderChart();
  }

  _renderChart() {
    this._chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',

        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ]
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="chart">hi</div>;
  }
}
```

Test (just verifying the 'Learn React' link is on the document. Seems the error is already fired in the import of the Chart component at the App.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Jest configured in package.json as following

```
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  }
```

While setupTests.js has nothing special but the following line

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

Comment: Please provide some code you have

Comment: @Dlucidone, Thanks for looking into this. I've added a sample code where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Please also provide jest.config.js

Comment: @seanplwong updated

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @WhiteMountain , what is the purpose of  setupTests.js file. In my codebase I don't have that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a similar issue: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/113

This is because jsdom doesn't provide an implementation for svg related api. If you follow the stacktrace to c3.js, you will find it is pointing right to

[image: c3 adding prototype]

you just need to provide the stub c3 need in `setupTests.js`:

```
window.SVGPathElement = jest.fn();
```

---

A side note: it is better to put `setupTests.js` somewhere else so that it will not get compiled or published.

Comment: it's not working for me. could you help if I am missing anything?

Comment: Can u provide more details like error msg/stack trace/description or better reproducible code @Ravindra

Comment: @seanplwong , what setupTests.js should contains?

Comment: the `setupTests.js` is an optional file, you could remove it if you don't need it. It usually contain some plugin setup like [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended). For the original post, it is setup for `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect`